# Winforms Space Invaders game bug with Ticker

Tags: c#, winforms

I´m writing a Space Invaders game in which I have 2 Tickers (invoked in 10 and 75ms intervals). For this purpose the 10ms Ticker is crucial.
The ticker indirectly calls the method you see below.
This method is responsible for the moving of the Invaders/ Aliens.

They first move rightwards till they reach the right border (ClientRectangle - 100), then they SHOULD move 30 pixels down and switch their currentWay leftwards. If they reach the left border (ClientRectangle + 100) they should also move 30 pixels down and again switch their currentWay.
The right and left moving is no problem and the down movement also works, BUT sometimes they move down 2 or 3 times (2 or 3 * 30 pixels).

I can´t figure out the problem. I guess that the ticker calls the method so often that the new position isn´t yet calculated.

```
private void MoveInvaders()
{
    bool downLeft = false;
    bool downRight = false;

    if (movedDown)
    {
        //rect = ClientRectangle of the Form
        //I´m using LINQ for some collision detection
        //The surface is the representation of the Invader as a Rectangle

        downRight = (from inv in invaders
                     where (inv.Surface.X + inv.Surface.Width) < rect.right - 100
                     select inv).ToList().Count > 0;

        if (!downRight)
        {
            downLeft = (from inv in invaders
                        where inv.Surface.X > rect.left + 100
                        select inv).ToList().Count > 0;
        }

        if (downRight || downLeft)
        {
            movedDown = false;
            downLeft = false;
            downRight = false;
        }

    }
    else
    {

        downRight = (from inv in invaders
                     where (inv.Surface.X + inv.Surface.Width) >= rect.right - 100
                     select inv).ToList().Count > 0;

        if (!downRight)
        {
            downLeft = (from inv in invaders
                        where inv.Surface.X <= rect.left + 100
                        select inv).ToList().Count > 0;
        }
    }

    foreach (Invader invader in invaders)
    {
        if (!movedDown)
        {
            if (downRight)
            {
                invader.Move(Way.Down);  //Their old Point.Y += 30
                currentWay = Way.Left;
            }
            else if (downLeft)
            {
                invader.Move(Way.Down);
                currentWay = Way.Right;
            }
        }

        invader.Move(currentWay);  //old Point.X += 1
    }

    if (!movedDown && (downLeft || downRight))
    {
        movedDown = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using `Timers` 10 ms will be too fast to called with any reliability.

Comment: @TaW I need 10ms to get a smooth framerate. I surely know, that WinForms isn´t the best Tool to create games, so i need to improve, I thought of maybe a timer who observe the "down movement" and you can only set it down once per second or sth...

Comment: There are several timers; do investigate them!  Since in winforms the repaint is not sych'ed with the monitor smoothness is hard to achieve.. (not that the aliens needs that, but the bullets do..)

Comment: Would it result into a nice solution, if i would trigger a third Ticker (1000ms or 500ms) only for setting the Way.Down? Instead of using my animationTicker (Which i prefer to allocate for my animations)? Or Could it happen that this one doesn´t set the Way.Down, because the bool get "refreshed" before this third ticker noticed to operate? Or is this just a question of the time interval?

Comment: There is no problem in using more timers. but the basic resolution will still not be guaranteed..

Comment: You didn't post enough code for someone to know exactly what's wrong. But it seems likely that you are somehow checking the "move down" logic before the actual movement has successfully gotten them out of the "move down" zone (i.e. they are supposed to reverse course, but do they actually manage to move enough to no longer be within 100 pixels of the client rect). Please post [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you would like an actual, precise answer.

Comment: Also, to reiterate the other comments: Windows simply will not be able to deliver a timer event with 10ms precision. At _best_, you might get 20ms precision, and typically you're looking at more like 50ms. Games usually get around this by running in a tight loop, watching the clock (e.g. `Stopwatch` class). Consumes a lot of CPU, but you get better timing. Finally, you can care about frame rate, or you can use LINQ, create intermediate `List<T>` objects, etc. but I don't think the two are really compatible.